# Error using Sharepoint REST API call to add permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have an odd issue. I have an integration that is doing lots of REST calls to SHarePoint all of which work fine, except for 2, setting permissions and creating libaries. The commands I'm using a literally textbook (cut and paste from, and they work OK from Power Automate, but not from my inegration platform (Workato) or PostMan. In both cases I get the error.
{   odata.error: {     code: -2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException,     message: {       lang: en-US,       value: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.     }   } }

I get the same responce from both my production SharePoint online instance and my Dev one (the dev is completely vanilla). I get the issue even when using Global Admin who is the site owner and admin.

An example call:

[https://s2j6.sharepoint.com/sites/PALWS-HwapuniSouth/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('History')/items(1)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=13,roledefid=1073741826)](https://s2j6.sharepoint.com/sites/PALWS-HwapuniSouth/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27History%27)/items(1)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=13,roledefid=1073741826))

All the scope variables are valid and work fine with other REST commands. I have broken inheritance as required of this command

Any ideas?

Comment: are any POSTs working from Workato or Postman? Have you added the request digest header in these requests? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/working-with-requestdigest

Comment: I wasn't setting the request digest header but it fails even when I do

These are the only two REST commands that don't work. All the rest work fine. I call numorous in the same script such as new site creation and folder creation.